# How to encapsulate a Map in DartLang?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this custom class that encapsulates a Map and I would like it works as a Map without having to extend a map:

```
class TournamentTree<T> {
  Map<int, List<Match<T>>> tree = <int, List<Match<T>>>{};

  set put (MapEntry<int, List<Match<T>>> entry) => tree[entry.key] = entry.value;

  bool get isEmpty => tree.isEmpty;

}
```

I've created that put method for now, but what I would like is to use this way:

```
tree[0] = matches;
```

or at least:

```
tree.put[0] = matches;
```

Comment: You can implement `operator []` and `operator []=` for your `TournamentTree` class.  You can compare to [`Map.operator []`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html) and [`Map.operator []=`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Map/operator_put.html) for examples  (although I would make `operator []` take your key type instead of an `Object`).

Comment: just what I needed, thanks